# Calculating residue of interesting function

Tags: complex-analysis

How to calculate $res_0 e^{\cot{z}}$ using definition ? I mean to calculate the integral. I’ve got a hint: I need to integrate over a rectangle, which vertical sides intersect real axis at points $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the their length is much bigger than the length of horizontal sides

Comment: Are you sure your singularities are poles? They could be essential.

Comment: Yes , I know that . Still I need to calculate the integral

Comment: Apply the hint :). To deal with the integrals over the vertical segments, notice that the integrand is periodic with period $\pi$. To find the limit of the integral over the horizontal segment $z = t + i A$ for $A \to \pm \infty$, use
$$\cot(t + i A) =
\frac {\sin 2 t - i \sinh 2 A} {\cosh 2 A - \cos 2 t}$$
and prove that you can interchange the integral and the limit.